# Update Related Field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do the below with django rest framework. I've got userprofile model that has a foreignkey tying back to the user table:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Role', choices=(('Administrator', 'Administrator'), ('User', 'User'), ('Warehouse Staff', 'Warehouse Staff')))
    adwebsite = models.ManyToManyField('ads.AdWebsite', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False, related_name='profile')
```

I'm using the following serializers:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    adwebsite = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('role', 'mobile', 'phone', 'adwebsite', 'terms_and_conditions')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    groups = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'profile')
        depth = 1
```

If I do a GET request, it's no problem I get all of the information from the profile relation. If I do a PUT, it updates the **User** model, but not the **UserProfile** model. My payload going to the server is correct, and no errors are reported, but it doesn't save the userprofile information.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nested serializer representations are currently read-only

Comment: I read that you where working on added this feature, is that still on the cards? or is there another way to do what I'm trying to do easily?

Comment: Yes, that's still incoming.