# update related Emailfield using source attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Pharmacy model with OnetoOneField to User model:

```
class Pharmacy(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fdo_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    dr_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I defined following serializer and ViewSet for both retrieving and updating Pharmacy model:

```
class PharmacySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')
    class Meta:
        model = Pharmacy
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'dr_name')

class PharmacyViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    model = Pharmacy
    serializer_class = PharmacySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

GET query is answered with correct email address but PUT query does not update email address (will do other fields).

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850718/update-related-field) which Tom Christie commented:

> Nested serializer representations are currently read-only

but I think my serialization is not considered as nested, and if it is, do you know a working solution to update both email and other information with single update request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your serialization is nested, even though in your Pharmacy model you only have one field from another model.

The best solution I came up with so far is overriding the *pre_save* method and to save the email address.  (this method is available from the UpdateMixin). Here is a short example:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    """
    obj is your object to be saved
    """
    user = obj.user
    user.email = self.request.DATA['email']
    user.save()
```

Of course, you can also override the *put* method, whichever suits you best.
Good luck!